# Centering checkbox/radio button in Materialize CSS

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

I'm having trouble getting checkboxes to center align using Materilize CSS.

```
<div class="center-align">

    <h5>Select Value </h5>

    <form action="#" >

            <p class="center-align">
              <input class="filled-in" name="group1" type="checkbox" id="1">
              <label for="1" class="teal-text text-lighten-2" >First</label>
            </p>
            <p class="center-align">
              <input  class="filled-in"name="group1" type="checkbox" id="2">
              <label for="2" class="teal-text text-lighten-2">Second</label><span></span>
            </p>
    </form>
```

[image]

This results in the checkboxes being aligned in the center, but offset from each other. If the labels are exactly the same, they match.

I've tried adding the center-align class to the `<div>` , `<form>`, `<input>` and the `<p>` but nothing is working as I'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to acheive desired result by adding this css

```
<style>
      label{  
          left: 50%;
        }   
</style>
```